# Saving special characters using FCK Editor

Tags: javascript, xhtml, fckeditor

I'm using FCK Editor, and in the Special Characters I've added °, degree (& deg; or & #176;).

When degree symbol is added, the source contains "& deg;", but when I'm sending to the server it is being assigned internal to a textarea and this degree symol is not being converted and is being sent as ° (degree), because of this the same is stored in mysql as special character, but when I'm accessing this in Javascript I'm getting into troubles.

Please let me know how to overcome this issue.

Regards

~ Please read without "space" between "& and deg;"  and "& #176;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve Special character issue you have to encode your fckeditor data using

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

And at the time of display you have to decode stored data back using

```
html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```